# Calendar control for cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, controls, calendar

I'm want to create a CRM app for me just for fun and to learn more about Cocoa, because CRM application evolve based on a Calendar, I wonder where can I get that cool Calendar control that iCal has in the iPhone.

I can't see it in my Library and I'm using SDK 3.0 beta 5.

And by the way, where can I get a free/paid controls collection like there are so many for the .NET world?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late to the party, but this question is answered here:

[Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps)

Comment: Thank you! I just asked to close my question as well, even if I did asked first

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not make the iPhone-style calendar UI part of the public API. You'll need to build your own calendar or contract it out.

Comment: Wow, that sorta sucks doesn't it?  You'd think they would want their developers to not have to worry about re-inventing this stuff.

Comment: Developers should file a feature request with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com. The more developers that ask for a UICalendar, the more likely we'll see one available.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1433889) on the Apple Support forums confirms what [Alex Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841206/calendar-control-for-cocoa-touch/841516#841516) says:

> No, does not exist (except in Apple's private library). I had to build one from scratch (actually I "outsourced" building the custom class to a Colorado iPhone development outfit via eLance) in order to develop my calendar-based app

The only thing I could find was [this](http://nrg.com.bd/blog/archives/36), which is a iPhone calendar control. It doesn't look identical to Apple's one, but it's close (and would probably be a good starting point if you need it to look similar)