# Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface, uikit, calendar

I am building an applicaiton for the iPhone that will display upcoming and past events. I settled for a list view, but then I realized that a calendar (just like the one displayed in the "month" view in the built-in Calendar application) would be a best match.

However, the iPhone Human Interface Guidelines just mentions the Date Picker, not the calendar, so I believe there is nothing like that out of the box. Is that true? If so, does anyone know of a third-party control that could be used? (I could write one myself, but I'd rather pick up something ready, since this is a departure on the original project plans).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes.

These are the option I am aware of:

**EDIT: as of May 6, 2010**

1) [GCCalendar](http://github.com/guicocoa/calendar)

2) http://github.com/klazuka/Kal

3) http://code.google.com/p/iphonecal (needs to be customized - easily - to change text from chinese to english)

4) Commercial: http://nrg.com.bd/blog/archives/36 but the look & feel of the previous ones is much, much better and they are free, if you can comply with their licenses.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! This is precisely what I was looking for. I ended up doing the first iteration of the app with a DatePicker and some UI enhancements around it, but I will surely look at #1 / #2. Thank you very much!

Comment: Pefect.. thanks unforgiven. 
btw, kcalendar-iphone is MIT license. IMO, thats the best choice if one is developing a commercial app.

Comment: I strongly agree. It's also my choice BTW.

Comment: kcalendar-iphone doesn't seem to be available anymore on Google Code.  Kal looks good though at http://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Comment: Hi may i know how the iCal works in iPad for month,whether they are using the Kal library or some other??

Comment: I am afraid this is Apple's proprietary code.

Comment: Then I have `CWCalendarView` over at https://github.com/jayway/CWUIKit, with support for annotation markers, max/min date, and invalidating dates for election, and more. In a 600 lines of code. Visually identical to iPhone Calendar app, in vector only, no images needed.

Comment: Since you are the selected correct answer and the calendars you have shown in your answer have not been updated for the past 4-6 years, would you mind adding this calendar to your list? Its updated to 2016, available through cocoapods, and is the best most configurable calendar i've seen to date. -> https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar

Comment: For simple Calendars, I suggest https://github.com/maximbilan/Calendar-iOS

Answer (score 30):

The best site is indeed https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Calendar, because you find screenshots of the separate calendars. Nevertheless, I made a list:

**iOS**

- [CLWeeklyCalendarView](https://github.com/clisuper/CLWeeklyCalendarView)
- [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)
- [TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/objc-TimesSquare)
- [VURIG Calendar](https://github.com/tjeerdintveen/Vurig-Calendar)
- [OCCalendar](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar)
- [PMCalendar](https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar)
- [CKCalendar](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar)
- [ABCalendarPicker](https://github.com/k06a/ABCalendarPicker)
- [MBCalendarKit](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit)
- [DSLCalendarView](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView)
- [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout)
- [NVCalendar](https://github.com/niravspaceo/NVCalendar)
- [VFCalendarView](https://github.com/wenzhishen/VFCalendarView)
- [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar)
- [ios-calendar](https://github.com/vgrichina/ios-calendar)
- [TKCalendarMonthView](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/blob/master/src/TapkuLibrary/TKCalendarMonthView.m)
- [MELiPadCalendar](https://github.com/Leveton/MELiPadCalendar)
- [MACalendarUI](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)
- [RDVCalendarView](https://github.com/robbdimitrov/RDVCalendarView)
- [RSDayFlow](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSDayFlow)
- [DayFlow](https://github.com/evadne/DayFlow)
- [PDTSimpleCalendar](https://github.com/jivesoftware/PDTSimpleCalendar)
- [SACalendar](https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar)
- [MNCalendarView](https://github.com/min/MNCalendarView)
- [CustomCalendar](https://github.com/micazeve/CustomCalendar)
- [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar)
- [THCalendarDatePicker](https://github.com/hons82/THCalendarDatePicker)
- [MZDayPicker](https://github.com/m1entus/MZDayPicker)
- [CustomCalendar](https://github.com/jubinjacob19/CustomCalendar)
- [DIDatepicker](https://github.com/noxt/DIDatepicker)
- [FSCalendar](https://github.com/f33chobits/FSCalendar)
- [WeekViewDemo](https://github.com/yshchan/WeekViewDemo)
- [FFCalendar](https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar)
- [CGCalendarView](https://github.com/CapitalGene/objc-CGCalendarView)
- [CalendarIOS7](https://github.com/leverdeterre/CalendarIOS7)
- [GCCalendar](https://github.com/guicocoa/calendar)
- [iphonecal](https://code.google.com/p/iphonecal/)
- [YFCalendar](https://github.com/tevendale/YFCalendar)
- [Upcoming](https://github.com/TeehanLax/Upcoming)
- [DPCalendar](https://github.com/maggix/DPCalendar)

**Xamarin.iOS**

- [FMCalendar](https://components.xamarin.com/view/fmcalendar)
- [TimesSquare Calendar](https://components.xamarin.com/view/timessquare)
- [XCalendar](https://components.xamarin.com/view/XCalendar)
- [Xamarin.Forms.Calendar](https://github.com/rid00z/Xamarin.Forms.Calendar)
- [escoz/monotouch-controls](https://github.com/escoz/monotouch-controls)

**Buy components**

- [Telerik.Xamarin.iOS](http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/calendar)
- [Resco Mobileformstoolkit](http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/details.aspx?comp=MonthCalendar&p=iOS)
- [Infragistics iOS Controls](http://www.infragistics.com/products/ios/widgets/calendar)

I have this in a [Excel-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PcRlAd_TTnzfsiyUG-U1XtVo1qbdDn61fOMGB1X5dOs/edit?usp=sharing), where you can find much more information.

Answer (score 12):

I would add [this](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) very good library.

Comment: Hi may i know how the iCal works in iPad for month,whether they are using the library or some other??

Answer (score 6):

Check out Kal: http://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Answer (score 4):

Your goto place for any question like this these days is cocoacontrols.com. Searching for "calendar"

[https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=calendar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

gives us 15 responses at post date; this one seems particularly appealing at first glance.

[DSLCalendarView for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dslcalendarview)

Answer (score 3):

> http://github.com/klazuka/Kal

is the best.

Comment: Kal does not have day view. Is there any (easy) way to add day view to it ?

Comment: Kal mimics iPhone Calendar app. I dunno if there is any with day view. People are always developing ... search for it, u  may get it.

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote my own (suitable for iPad / landscape view, scrollable, stylable, builds on Three20) – http://www.componentix.com/blog/22

On GitHub – https://github.com/vgrichina/ios-calendar

Answer (score 2):

The library for the custom controller for calendar.

1) [OCCalendar](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar)

2) [PMCalendar](https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar)

3) [MAWeekView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/maweekview)

4) ios-calendar

5) [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

6) [CKCalendar](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar)

Hope it will help you fine.Available on git also.

Comment: Please post links to them..

Comment: Currently checked out the OCCalendar link it is mentioned that is code is deprecated. Pl. refer to the below link https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar. Any input on whether this calendar module is still supported.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly newer contender that works better in the iOS7 world is [TimesSquare](https://github.com/square/objc-TimesSquare).

I used Tapku for a long time but haven't found it all that flexible, and the code is really hard to modify.

Answer (score 0):

There are also other new version custom visual calendar for iOS 8+ written in Swift (2.0) [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar). It provides easily customisable calendar control for iOS.

[DDCalendarView](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDCalendarView) which looks similar to iCal. It has both ObjectiveC and Swift version of code. Currently it shows only daily events. we need to develop the UI to support weekly and monthly events. Event classes used in this calendar are not inherited from EKEventKit classes.