# Are there any Calendar View components out there?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am looking for component that draws a calendar grid View, similar to Apple's "Calendar" app.

Can't find anything on google. searching for "calendar" or calendar, view, component is too generic term to find anything useful.

There are a lot of apps in appstore that have calendars, do they program calendar views at low-level by drawing each day as Rects, etc?

Or it's possible to use some available component libraries?

Comment: Yes, definitely.
For current component options, see my previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps/997960#997960)

Comment: thanks. strangely when I searched before posting I didn't get above post in results.

Comment: Just to add up, be aware that the freely available ones contain some leaks.

Comment: This may have been better marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Your goto place for any question like this these days is cocoacontrols.com. Searching for "calendar"

[https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=calendar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

gives us 15 responses; this one seems particularly appealing at first glance.

[DSLCalendarView for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dslcalendarview)