# What is the name of iPhone Calendar table?

Tags: iphone, sdk

i want to know what is the iphone calendar table ? and how could implement it .

[alt text http://patrickmd.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/iphone_calendar_sshot.png](http://patrickmd.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/iphone_calendar_sshot.png)

and i need some information about these questions :

does it way change the data of calendar ? and creat for example persian calendar ?
how could import events to the table ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This component doesn't exist in the native library, if you want something like that you'll have to make it yourself. But it exist some projects already made. You can find one here:
[Creating Native Calendar Like View](http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-development-creating-native_09.html).

Comment: thank you .. but the table is not good ! :-S have you another project ? or sample ?

Comment: I have found this library too: http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary (It seems me to be a good project but I have not tested it)
But I don't know if it'll be ok for you.
May be in the next sdk Apple will open his calendar API, but for the moment there is nothing.

Comment: No probs. =) Think to validate the question to mark this topic as answered.