# Calendar control for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, open-source, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps)

Are there are calendar controls for iPad. I know a few which are available for the iPhone:
[iOS Calendar Views](http://www.e-string.com/content/ios-calendar-views)

Comment: Not really. That thread discusses calendar control options for the iPhone, whereas i'm interested in a calendar control for the iPad. Bigger iPhone :)

Comment: And thus you expanded on your question ;)

Comment: Why is this question closed? The link provided contains calendar for iPhone, where as question is asked for iPads specifically. Foolish moderators!

Answer (score 1):

I remade and rearranged Kal for the iPad, but it's a poor substitute for some of the private/commercial implementations I've seen. If you want to take a look, mine is at https://www.GitHub.com/grgcombs/Kal

Comment: Not an answer. A good calendar control for IPAD Is [FFCalendar](https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar)