# Calendar source code for iphone iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, image, background, calendar

I was looking for some sample code to create a really simple calendar like this one

[image]

but i can find nothing at all... only like the default iphone agenda with appointments... can you help me with some link?

Many thanks!
M.

Comment: Many similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348403/calendar-control-for-ipad

Comment: I already read this post like many other similar ones but it is not what i mean... i don't want a native iphone calendar but like the image.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to implement native kal calender source code from search.it is really easy

implementation of calender and moreover its interface is resembling with iPhone default calender view.