# Xcode: Calendar for Ipad or Iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, datetime, calendar, datapicker

I have a technical question: In xcode there is only a data-picker and this element is not functional in my app because in my app the user must be fast to choose date time. I would to use another instrument for chose a date. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use one of the Date pickers lots of web sites are using : some kind of calendar view where you touch at the day you want.
You may have to code your own component though.

Examples :
http://www.bitrepository.com/a-collection-of-free-javascript-date-pickers.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? You want an existing web solution, like JavaScript? Or do you want an existing Objective C component that behave like those JS calendar pickers?

Comment: I want an existing web solution