# Calendar like app in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I am a beginner to iPhone Development. I want to develop a iPhone app which is like Native IOS Calendar.

The app should display the days and months in grid, list, month views...

I dont know how to dynamically change months and clear the previous months data...

In the native app, it changes the dates of months with animation... How to do this..

I dont want to use any open source project.. i want to create from my own code...

Kindly give me an idea or reference link to do this...

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps ?

Comment: @KarthikCan you tell me which library or sample application you have referred to display native IOS calender?

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[image]

Download [Kal](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kal) or [TapKu calendar](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-calendar) and read their source code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... The Kal calender has no NIB files and i cant understand... If it is possible, please give me core concept behind the calender... i will try my own...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Kal Calendar](https://github.com/powow/Kal)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the weeks of the calendar are a part of a table view controller. These will be linked to a managed datasource behind the class.

The UIView has methods by which you can define how the view transitions from one state to another.

The bes place to start is with the iOS developer library...

[UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)