# What is the best calendar library for iPad applications?

Tags: ipad, interface, calendar

There are a number of calendar libraries for iPhone applications, but most of them don't work properly with the iPad.

Does anyone know of a third-party control/library that could be used for calendars on the iPad?

More about iPhone calendar libraries: [Is there any ready-made calendar control for iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `CWCalendarView` over at https://github.com/jayway/CWUIKit works on iPad.

Visually it looks like the months view from iPhone Calendar app. It is only the actual month view grid. The project have an example app where the view is used as a date picker in a popover, with validation of selectable dates using min/max date and delegate callbacks.

Fits as-is in for example to show a calendar in the top-left corner of an iPad app. The source is not even 600 lines of code. So even easier to change for your needs (all other calendar views I have seen count the thousands of LOC, spread over a half dozen files).

Comment: Thank you for your rely, but I sticked to great open source library Tapku.

Comment: tapku is the solution...it was exactly what i wanted. go [here](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)