# iPhone day calendar view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, calendar

Before I make the dive and make it myself, is there any open source solution to have a day calendar in my iPhone app? I need a view which resembles the 'Day' view in the actual Apple Calendar iPhone app.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.e-string.com/content/ios-calendar-views

I would recommend [GCCalendar](https://github.com/guicocoa/calendar).

Another one that was created by the developer of GooCal is [muhku](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui). This one allows calendar event overlapping.