# How to implement calender in a vertical UIScrollView showing all 24 months from today's date in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, calendar, tapku

Does anyone know how to show calendar in a vertical UIScrollView starting from today's date till 24 months from now? I want to implement this in iPad. Is there any such api for iOS?

Comment: Hi i have uploaded the code [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65213224/CalDemo%202.zip) making use of tapku library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for drawing a calendar.  You might find one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997779/is-there-any-ready-made-calendar-control-for-iphone-apps) useful as a starting point.

Comment: But this are simple calendar. i want 24 months calendar scrolling.

Comment: That's why I said “useful as a starting point”, not “useful as a ready-made solution to your exact problem”.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement it?

Comment: My idea for implementing it is to put a bunch of subviews in a scroll view.  I don't know of any shortcuts.

Comment: @Dhara did you find the solution for your requirement ? if yes please share it with me here

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65213224/CalDemo%202.zip u cab download the code from here. I have already written this in the questions comment