# calendar view in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, calendar

how to create calendar view in iphone sdk like

in following link

http://jonathanwatmough.com/

Regards,
sathish

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar control for cocoa touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841206/calendar-control-for-cocoa-touch)

Comment: you can read this blog http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244 it may help you

Answer (score 2):

I use Kal for calendar interfaces. It's kind of shocking that there's no built-in calendar view controller, but there's not. I really expected them to add one with EventKit in iOS4, but no.

Kal's a little tricky to get your head around, but once you understand how it thinks, it's easy enough to implement.

http://github.com/klazuka/Kal