# open source calender for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am looking for the open source calendar in iphone sdk, any ideas ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar control for cocoa touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841206/calendar-control-for-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [klazuka/Kal](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal) which implements the month view exactly like the iPhone's calendar

Answer (score 1):

Another great one is in the [tapkulibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) on github.